# PHP Thumbnail from image from url

Tags: php, image, url, thumbnails

I'm using the code, that first checks filenames in folder and then creates url. In the url find it the special line where is an imagefile. It displays correctly image and address, but if images are too big, takes it so long time. Is it possible to create thumbnail and display this instead of image? Thank You!

```
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$files = scandir('files/');
foreach($files as $file) {
    if($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;
    $file = basename($file, ".html");
    $url = 'http://address.com/test/'.$file;
    $html = file_get_html($url);
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
    if (strpos($element,'address.com') !== false) {
    $url = $element->src;
    echo $url.'</br>';
    echo '<IMG SRC="',$url, '" WIDTH="128" HEIGHT="96" BORDER="0" ALT="" /><br/>';
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use CSS `clip:rect(50px 218px 155px 82px);`

Setting width and height does not decress the ACTUAL image size, so load time will still take just as long.  See this article on step by step `div` creation and `css` coding.

http://www.seifi.org/css/creating-thumbnails-using-the-css-clip-property.html

Also as a side note, nothing beats ACTUALLY MAKING TUMBNAILS!  There are serve side thumbnail generators, but this is the best you'll get with out actually making tumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post on [How to proportionally resize uploaded images](http://www.geekality.net/?p=1564), you should be able to adjust the code from [the sample I wrote](http://samples.geekality.net/view-source.php?file=image-resize/upload.php) to do what you want.

Pasting the code below in case my site dies in the future.

```
<?php

// *snip* Removed form stuff
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($pathToImage);


// Target dimensions
$max_width = 240;
$max_height = 180;


// Calculate new dimensions
$old_width      = imagesx($image);
$old_height     = imagesy($image);
$scale          = min($max_width/$old_width, $max_height/$old_height);
$new_width      = ceil($scale*$old_width);
$new_height     = ceil($scale*$old_height);


// Create new empty image
$new = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);


// Resample old into new
imagecopyresampled($new, $image, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 
        $new_width, $new_height, $old_width, $old_height);


// Catch the image data
ob_start();
imagejpeg($new, NULL, 90);
$data = ob_get_clean();


// Destroy resources
imagedestroy($image);
imagedestroy($new);


// Output image data
header("Content-type: image/jpeg", true, 200);
echo $data;
```

You'd probably want to stick this in a function and change it output to a file. Then generate the thumbnail in your foreach loop and link to the thumbnail instead of the original. You should also check if you have already created a thumbnail for an image so you don't do it more than once for each image.